# In memory data structure with multiple geo indexes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation, geospatial, kdtree

I have a pandas dataframe which includes two 4 columns which are latitudes and longitudes of an origin and a destination cooridnate here is the schema:

id | originLatitude | originLongitude | destinationLatitude | destinationLongitude | otherColumns

now I need something such as a `kdtree` or `GeoPandas` but here are my problems with them:

- I can't have index on both origin and destination using `kdtree`
- I can't find a way to have indexes on two coordinate columns in `geopandas`

If I wanted to use a DB postgres for example had spatial index support known as PostGIS but can you help me to find some procedure to perform fast in memory filters on these columns?

Comment: why not maintain 2 kdtrees or 2 dataframes?

Comment: @ely well that is a solution but I'm seeking a singular data structure for this purpose.